# Disabling the Radio in Portal

Tags: portal

I bought Portal via Steam -- at some point they released an update that added a small radio to each level playing a muzak version of the *Still Alive* song. Googling indicates this is part of an easter egg.

Is there any way to disable the music this radio plays?  It's super annoying (to me) and ruins the atmosphere.

I've found mention online of a way to replace the looping_radio_mix.wav files on a PC, but

1. I'm using Steam on a Mac
2. I wasn't able to find looping_radio_mix.wav anywhere on my hard drive

Comment: The small radios have been there since start of the game... Messing with the Data of a game is never a good idea if you do not know exactly what your doing. You could eather turn the Musik in options down or destroy the radio in game. PS: There are achivements and hidden Audio Wave Pictures Coded in those little Radios

Comment: @GEnGEr The radios were always there, but until the pre-portal 2 update they didn't play the the Muzak version of the Portal theme on every level.  With the addition of these radios the mood and atmosphere of the game is changed considerably, and that change isn't to some people's taste.  I'd like to play the game I originally downloaded.

Comment: How about downgrade it ?

Comment: ohh ok, if i could give you a hint there is a webside for speedrunning purpose that has older versions of Steam games, because of bug using in older versions ... but thats of toppic if you know what i mean ;P

Comment: @GEnGEr Downgrading via Steam seems like it's a non-deterministic endeavor.

Comment: I agree, it is very annoying!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have found [this thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1288419&page=5), they suggest a variety of methods for getting rid of the music, and one of them is replacing the looping_radio_mix.wav that you mentioned.

> I wasn't able to find looping_radio_mix.wav anywhere on my hard drive

Could you describe how and where did you look for it, what else did you find (if any), or where does Steam keep its files on a Mac?

If all else fails, try voting and commenting on [this Github issue](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Source-1-Games/issues/384), and hope you are raising the developers' attention to the problem.

Comment: Spotlight search for "looping_radio_mix.wav", find . -name 'looping_radio_mix.wav' in my ~/Library folder.

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly deduced, removing/replacing `looping_radio_mix.wav` is probably the way to go. On my mac (Steam defaults) all the sound files for portal are in this folder:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/Portal/portal/sound/
```

Hit ⇧⌘G in Finder and paste the above path to get there. I *don't* have the file specified, but I don't know why. I can't open Portal right now and see if I have the music playing.